# git / windows: How to avoid that Git always add all my personal folder?

Tags: windows, git

I have installed git on my pc
I create a test folder on my desktop and go there through
 `cd Desktop/test`

When typing in `git status` I got the content of all my files `'c:\users\myuser'`
so when I type in `git add -A`, I have a many giga .git folder !

I guess git has a BAD path somewhere so it adds all my c:\users\myuser files and folder: how to fix that ?

(osrry I am new to git !)

Answer (score 0):

So you created a folder on your desktop, but you didn't `git init` which means it's not a repository yet. `git status` shouldn't normally work, so that means you've got a parent folder that is an initialized repository. In your case, it's in your home directory. Delete that `.git` folder, initialize one in new folder, and then add files.

```
cd c:\users\myuser
rm -r -force .git

cd Desktop/test
git init
```

[image: powershell screenshot]

Comment: I think you mean `cd c:/users/myuser`?  I don't know of a system that both a) has `rm` and b) doesn't have a shell that uses backslashes for quoting.

Comment: @EdwardThomson no, I mean what I said. Powershell is a popular Windows platform. I posted a screenshot FYI. It actually converts all forward slashes in a path to backslashes, so you can use either.

Answer (score -1):

Change your current work directory to the responsitory before you type .

Comment: The question said he already did `cd Desktop/test` so your answer isn't clear to me.